# metro-ui datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, microsoft-metro

I am trying to use Datepicker from http://metroui.org.ua/datepicker.html with no success. I already put all files as in original page, checked all requirements - nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>FinalList</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/metro/metro-bootstrap.min.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/metro/iconFont.min.css ">
<script src="js/metro/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/prettify.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="metro">
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="input-control text" data-role="datepicker" data-week-start="1">
            <input type="text">
            <button class="btn-date"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these external file in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/docs.css">

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-bootstrap.css">

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/metro.min.js"></script>
```

`<body>` Code

```
<div class="metro">
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="input-control text" data-role="datepicker" data-week-start="1">
            <input type="text">
            <button class="btn-date"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9umbmwq0/2/)

Comment: The problem was about declaring `jquery.widget.min.js` after `jquery.widget.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing it in action, I think if you add http: to both cdn.datatables.net lines and just re-arrange the head section like this you should get it working :)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/metro/metro-bootstrap.min.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/metro/iconFont.min.css ">
<script src="js/metro/metro.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/prettify.js"></script>
```

Comment: omitting the http: makes it so it works whether your page is under http or https

Answer (score 0):

The following input tag can be used to input the required date format

```
 <input type="text" data-role="calendarpicker" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY">
```

Comment: <input type="text" data-role="calendarpicker" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY">